# Autoincrement not written to object

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy as my ORM layer to access my MySQL Database.

Here is the table, mapper and model, I'm talking about:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    uid INT(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    display_name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    timezone VARCHAR(96) NOT NULL,
    join_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    last_login DATETIME NOT NULL,
    verified INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid),
    UNIQUE (email)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, id=0, email="", password="", displayName="",
                 timezone="UTC", joinDate=None, lastLogin=None, verified=False):
    self.id = id
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.displayName = displayName
    self.timezone = timezone
    self.joinDate = joinDate or datetime.utcnow()
    self.lastLogin = lastLogin or datetime.utcnow()
    self.verified = verified


userTable = sqlalchemy.Table('user', meta, autoload=True)

sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(models.User, userTable, properties={
    'id': userTable.c.uid,
    'displayName': userTable.c.display_name,
    'joinDate': userTable.c.join_date,
    'lastLogin': userTable.c.last_login
}
```

The problem is, that whenever I try to insert an object into the database via the orm layer, I expect the newly generated ID to be stpred in my original object for future reference. Otherwise this whole thing would be pretty useless for me.

```
>>> session = Session()
>>> u = User(0, 'test@example.com', 'asdf', 'Test User')
>>> session.add(u)
>>> session.flush()
>>> u.id
0
```

Does anyone know how to tell SQLALchemy to save the ID into the original object? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried passing a NULL (or None or whatever it uses for NULL) instead of zero?

Comment: +1 - NULL is not the same as zero. NULL uses the next auto_increment ID, whereas zero uses a literal zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, @msw and @Aya are right. The object's id attribute must be None before insertion into the database.